# Persistent global kernel objects in windows?

Tags: windows, kernel, shared-memory

Is there a version of CreateFileMapping or a similar function that is not reference counted?  I have a situation where I would like a file mapping to stay up forever, even after terminating all processes that are using it.  If I have to, I can use a service that stays up forever, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: In user mode?  I shouldn't think so, but you could get the same effect by injecting a handle to the object into a persistent process such as `wininit` or `lsass`.

Comment: I thought I read something about a new change allowing this type of operation, but I can't find it.